# Почему Entity Framework выдает ошибку, если я прописываю собственные get и set?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, entity

В таком виде, который с генерировал сам Entity Framework, всё работает нормально:

```
  public partial class man
    {
        public int Id_Men { get; set; }
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> Birthday { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Height { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Weight { get; set; }

        public man()
        {

        }
        public man(string fIO, DateTime? birthday, double? height, double? weight)
        {

            FIO = fIO;
            Birthday = birthday;
            Height = height;
            Weight = weight;
        }
}
```

Но если я пытаюсь прописать свои get and set, то он выдает ошибку:

```
  namespace WPF_application.Models 
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class man : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public int Id_Men { get; set; }
        public string FIO;
        public Nullable<DateTime> Birthday;
        public Nullable<double> Height;
        public Nullable<double> Weight;

        public man()
        {

        }
        public man(string fIO, DateTime? birthday, double? height, double? weight)
        {

            FIO = fIO;
            Birthday = birthday;
            Height = height;
            Weight = weight;
        }

        public string Fio
        {
            get { return FIO;}
            set
            {
                if (this.FIO == value) return;
                this.FIO = value;
                onPropertyChanged("FIO");
            }
        }

        public DateTime Birthday_
        {
            get { return (DateTime)Birthday; }
            set
            {
                if (this.Birthday == value) return;
                this.Birthday = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Birthday");
            }
        }

        public double Height_
        {
            get { return (double)Height; }
            set
            {
                if (this.Height == value) return;
                this.Height = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Height");
            }
        }

        public double Weight_
        {
            get { return (double)Weight; }
            set
            {
                if (this.Weight == value) return;
                this.Weight = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Weight");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void onPropertyChanged (string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The entity type man is not part of the model for the current context."

Это исключение появляется когда через DbContext выгружаются данные:

```
   class ServiceMan
    {
        public List<man> getAllMan()
        {
            var dbContext = new peopleDbContext();

            IQueryable<man> query = dbContext.men;

            List<man> list_man = query.ToList();//

            return list_man;
        }       

    }

    public partial class peopleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public peopleDbContext()
            : base("name=db_peopleEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<man> men { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Почему это происходит и можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Сделайте поля приватными, а свойствам измените имена, чтобы они совпадали с моделью.

Comment: Пробую: public int Id_Men { get; set; }
        private string FIO;
        private DateTime Birthday;
        private Nullable<double> Height;
        private Nullable<double> Weight;

Comment: public string Fio
        {
            get { return FIO;}
            set
            {
                if (this.FIO == value) return;
                this.FIO = value;
                onPropertyChanged("FIO");
            }
        }

Comment: public DateTime Birthday_
        {
            get { return (DateTime)Birthday; }
            set
            {
                if (this.Birthday == value) return;
                this.Birthday = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Birthday");
            }
        }

Comment: Выводит туже ошибку. Назвать свойство тем же именем не дает - говорит уже существует

Comment: Свойство `Birthday`, поле `_birthday`.

Comment: Да, это сработало! Это ответ! Огромное спасибо!